Visa Expired at Malaysia and want to go back my country
My visa is expired at Malaysia 3 months ago. I want to go back Myanmar now? What should I do.

I don't want to go to immigration,.could i buy air ticket and can i go back.

The simpler answer: go back, and you may get a ban or fines. Or do you want to do some damage control, e.g. because you want to go back to Malaysia? Or do you have good reasons for the overstay?

I'm sure Malaysia will be happy to be rid of you, though they may issue a ban from entering the country for several years as a penalty for you violating your visa requirements (and maybe a fine as well).
If you've committed no other crimes in Malaysia (and yes, visa overstay is a crime) they're very unlikely to throw you in prison.
What's the problem returning to Burma? Every country tends to be happy to see their citizens return home.
What to do? Book a flight to Rangoon or anywhere else in Burma you can fly to from Malaysia. Unless of course you no longer have a valid passport in which case a visit to your own country's consulate or embassy in Malaysia is called for first to arrange for a replacement.

Do you know anything about Malaysian law or you're just talking based on your usual prejudice? Visa overstay isn't necessarily a crime.

@Relaxed visa overstay pretty much everywhere is a crime, especially long overstay that's not reported. You're in the country no more legally than if you'd entered without a visa altogether. But your usual prejudice is showing, as usual.

Is it possible to travel overland? Myanmar citizens don't need a visa to Thailand.

@jwenting No, it's not. Presence might be illegal without being a crime, those are two completely different concepts. Heck, it's even possible to be detained and removed without having committed or ever be charged with a crime. You clearly don't know about immigration or the law in general so my question stands: Do you actually know anything about Malaysia before giving potentially dangerous or misleading advice to the OP?

https://conventuslaw.com/report/overstaying-in-malaysia-a-strict-liability-immigration-offence/ According to this source, overstaying a visa in Malaysia is an "immigration offence" against the Immigration Act. It is NOT a criminal offence against the Penal Code.

@jwenting I'm pretty sure that almost everywhere in the EU, overstaying a visa by 3 months is NOT a crime. Yes, you'll get a fine and a ban, but it's not a crime. A crime (or a criminal offence) is a legal term with a specific meaning. Not everything that carries a penalty is a crime. For example, riding a train without a ticket is also not a crime in many jurisdictions.
